# Unexpected result when creating Getters/Setters

Tags: java, xpages, naming-conventions

When I created a JAVA Class I set some private variables then had it create the getters and setters. When I did I got some strange results. here is a code snippet of the class:

```
private String xPageName;
private String nameXPage;

public String getXPageName() {
        return xPageName;
}
public void setXPageName(String pageName) {
        xPageName = pageName;
}
public String getNameXPage() {
        return nameXPage;
}
public void setNameXPage(String nameXPage) {
        this.nameXPage = nameXPage;
}
```

the getter and setter for the variable xPageName is way different than I expected. I created another variable aPageName and got the same strange resulting getter and setter. Is there a JAVA naming convention that does something different with the lower case first letter and uppercase second letter?

Comment: no, that is java pattern for setter and getter methods

Comment: Could you post the code you were expecting "it" to create?  (I assume that "it" here is "xpages"?  Your question isn't really clear on that.)

Comment: If you auto-generated the setters/getters, the tool probably used camel-case variable naming convention. Obviously, you can go against convention and name it something else. But there's a reason conventions exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior seems to be specific to Domino Designer (8.5.3 and 9.0.1). It does create the following setters:

```
private String aaPage;
private String aPage;
private String aPa;
private String aP;
private String a;

public void setAaPage(String aaPage) {
    this.aaPage = aaPage;
}
public void setAPage(String page) {
    aPage = page;
}
public void setAPa(String pa) {
    aPa = pa;
}
public void setAP(String ap) {
    aP = ap;
}
public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
}
```

The three middle generated setters are in fact weird. This "special" parameter for setters gets created when you choose "Source / Generate Getters and Setters...". Because the parameter name is different to the private field name it doesn't need to add "this.".

Although it's weird it doesn't mean it's wrong. But, it doesn't really follow the usual conventions...

Setters are generated the normal way if you click STRG+1 in line `private String ...` and choose "Create getter and setter for '...'".

In Eclipse (Juno) works all as expected.

Comment: I did the test on aPageName and aaPageName with the same result.

Comment: I've never had the effect so far because I always press **STRG+1** at the end of a new private field line and generate the getter and setter right away.

Comment: That is unusual, I did a <crtl>1 and created the getter and setter at the end of the line and it worked as I would expect it to. So the source/create Getters & setters works a bit differently from the <ctrl>1 at the end of the private String xPageName; line. Interesting.

Comment: Yes, it is unusual and in this case kind of a workaround. It's good you found out what I meant with STRG - it is the name of CTRL key on a German keyboard :-). So yes, **CTRL+1** creates the correct setters.

Answer (score 1):

The convention for method names in java is [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), which means the first word is lower case, and all the next words are capitalized.

That's why the x in `xPageName`, which is treated as a word, is changed to upper case when it's no longer the first word (as in `getXPageName`).

Answer (score 1):

You may of forgot the 'this' in your setxPageName. I used the automatic getters and setters generator in spring tool suite and got this:

```
private String xPageName;
private String nameXPage;

public String getxPageName() {
    return xPageName;
}
public void setxPageName(String xPageName) {
    this.xPageName = xPageName;
}
public String getNameXPage() {
    return nameXPage;
}
public void setNameXPage(String nameXPage) {
    this.nameXPage = nameXPage;
}
```

So maybe captilizing the x in your xPageName functions is the problem

Comment: See the comments from Knut in his answer. The getters and setters were created by selecting Right Click/Source/Create Getters & Setters. So in my example I didn't forget anything that is how they were created for me. If you go private String xPageName;<ctrl>+1 you get the getter & setter as you would expect them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the one setter that doesn't use the "this" keyword?
That's strange for sure, but you can add it if you like.
Is this code produced by the Java editor of DDE? Never had that effect...

Comment: Yes I'm using the JAVA Editor DDE in the Notes Designer- it seems to miss the this for some reason. Also the x is missing from the setXPageName and should be this.xPageName = xPageName not this:
public void setXPageName(String pageName) {
        xPageName = pageName;
}
I tried aPageName and got the same result it seems to get confused by a single character lowercase first name. If I careate a variable xxPageName it sets teh getters and setters correctly. Very strange.

Comment: Hmmm as a I posted: never came across with this issue though I'm using it excessivly in my current project. Did you create a PMR for that?

Comment: I think you can force the "this" in via a preference.  But overall the code should be fine I think.

Comment: The <crtl>+1 at the end of the variable definition line works correctly. So long as the first work is 2 or more lowercase letters the source.create setters & getters works fine see Knut's test results above.